# Does Cassandra repair delta within partition keys?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

When Cassandra does a repair, it calculates a Merkle tree and then streams the data for the tree leaf nodes that differ. Does the Merkle tree take clustering keys into account? That is, if two nodes have a single partition key with a clustering key and the partition keys have different clustering keys, will Cassandra only stream the clustering keys that differ? Or will Cassandra nodes always stream the full partition keys?

Clearly, the above has implications as to how one should model data to speed up repairs.

Comment: I didn't understand your question. A partition keys is never split between nodes, so two nodes can't have a single partition key. Perhaps you could word the question differently?

Comment: @LHWizard Two nodes can hold the same partition key if you have RF>1.

Comment: an interesting thought exercise - the partition key is assigned to one node, and an algorithm decides which other nodes get the replicas. but only one node holds responsibility for the token range that the partition belongs to. I get your point now though.